# Removing package.json or part of it from app in electron-forge

Tags: electron, electron-forge

I have started using electron-forge. My package.json is begin added to the final output after making and packaging.

The package.json contains info which I dont want to to be in production. Such as devDependencies or scripts. Putting package.json in forge.config.js ignore list breaks the build.

Is there a way to remove the file or hide ceratin parts of it in the final packaged app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `postPackage` hook within your `forge.config.js` file, like so for example:

```
{
    hooks: {
        postPackage: async (forgeConfig, options) => {
            console.info('postPackage() Packages built at:', options.outputPaths);
            if (!(options.outputPaths instanceof Array)) {
                return;
            }
            const packageDotJson = path.join(options.outputPaths[0], 'resources', 'app', 'package.json');
            const content = fs.readFileSync(packageDotJson);
            const json = JSON.parse(content.toString());
            Object.keys(json).forEach((key) => {
                switch (key) {
                    case 'name': {
                        break;
                    }
                    case 'version': {
                        break;
                    }
                    case 'main': {
                        break;
                    }
                    case 'author': {
                        break;
                    }
                    case 'description': {
                        break;
                    }
                    default: {
                        delete json[key];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
            fs.writeFileSync(packageDotJson, JSON.stringify(json, null, '\t'));
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks.

Note that I had to change the path of packageDotJson to the following when building on mac os m1:

`const packageDotJson = path.join(options.outputPaths[0], 'ai-document-sorter.app', 'Contents', 'Resources', 'app', 'package.json');`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Ini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4764917/ini).

But I could't get it to work using [postPackage](https://www.electronforge.io/config/hooks#postpackage), I think it is because I am using [asar](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/asar-archives).

I got it to work using [packageAfterPrune](https://www.electronforge.io/config/hooks#packageafterprune), changing the file before it is packaged into the `app.asar` file.

```
hooks: {
  packageAfterPrune: async (forgeConfig, buildPath) => {
    const packageDotJsonPath = path.resolve(buildPath, 'package.json');
    const packageDotJson = fs.readFileSync(packageDotJsonPath);
    const json = JSON.parse(packageDotJson.toString());
    Object.keys(json).forEach((key) => {
      switch(key){
        case 'name': {
          break;
        }
        case 'version': {
          break;
        }
        case 'main': {
          break;
        }
        case 'author': {
          break;
        }
        case 'description': {
          break;
        }
        default: {
          delete json[key];
          break;
        }
      }
    });
    fs.writeFileSync(packageDotJsonPath, JSON.stringify(json, null, '\t'));
  }
}
```

Please let me know if this way is a bad way to do this, but maybe someone else is in the same situation as I was.

Edit: This is only tested on MacOs!